# IdentityServer lock users to the clients

Tags: asp.net-identity, multi-tenant, identityserver4

Identityserver4 gives SSO out of the box with unlimited clients and api resources.

If we want to restrict users to access only a specified clients, whats the best way to implement?

**Approach 1**

- Mapping table for userId and clientId
- on login/ back channel calls, After verifying the user, an additional check to see if the authenticated user has a client mapping if so do a check and return accordingly.

with the above approach how do we handle SSO? if user logged into another client and when tried to access a restricted client, still logs in because the cookie authentication kicks off and allows user to log in.

How do we restrict this behaviour on identityserver? (with aspnetidentity)..

**Approach 2**

- Pass acr_values in the authentication context request
- Have a userstore to support tenant id by extending the IdentityUser with tenantid ([like this](https://www.scottbrady91.com/ASPNET-Identity/Quick-and-Easy-ASPNET-Identity-Multitenancy))

Might hit the same issue as mentioned above when user logged in another client and tries to login on the restricted client which idsrv might say ok because of the SSO cookie..

I'm currently working on a sample app to see this in action. Appreciate any help solving the above issue mentioned

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am facing the same problem right now

Answer (score 1):

In **Approach 1** the authorize endpoint is still invoked even if the user is already signed in and has a cookie. You can use an `ICustomAuthorizeRequestValidator` (registered using `AddCustomAuthorizeRequestValidator()`) to do additional validation checks and return an error if the user does not meet the requirements you set out.